# Creating an array of objects from a CSV

Tags: java, arrays, loops, csv

So I have some words on a CSV file that I have read in and have made sure that they have been accurately read in by printing them out, but I'm stuck on how I can take these and assign them each to a specific object within an array. The reason I have 15 in my for loop is because I have 15 different `Card` objects that I need to create from my CSV file.

**Question: How can I create an array of several `Card` objects that I have parsed and read in?**

```
public class Driver {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberOfPlayers;
    int playerNumber;

    //reads in Cards.txt
    File cards = new File("./src/Cards.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(cards);

for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    //while there is a new line in the data, goes to the next one
    while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
        Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
        lineScanner.useDelimiter(", ");

        //while there is a new attribute to read in on a given line, reads data
        while(lineScanner.hasNext())
        {
            String cardType = lineScanner.next(); 
            String message = lineScanner.next();
            Double amount = lineScanner.nextDouble();

            //creates a Card
            Card myCard = new Card(cardType, message, amount);
            Card myCards[] = new Card[i]; //stuck here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the array outside the loop, and then add to it inside the loop.

Just before the loop you can have

```
Card[] myCards = new Card[15];
```

Then in your loop you can have

```
//creates a card
Card myCard = new Card(cardType, message, amount);
myCards[i] = myCard;
```

You also need to change the structure of your loops. The first while loop will read every line in the file, and the second one will read every card in that line, which is actually not what you want. You want to read one card per loop. This code should look like this

```
Card[] myCards = new Card[15];
// only run this if the file has at least 1 line, and only run once
if (fileScanner.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
    lineScanner.useDelimiter(", ");

    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {

        // read in one card
        if (lineScanner.hasNext())
        {
            String cardType = lineScanner.next();
            String message = lineScanner.next();
            Double amount = lineScanner.nextDouble();

            //creates a card
            Card myCard = new Card(cardType, message, amount);
            myCards[i] = myCard;
        }
    }
}
```

Check out Oracle's Array documentation on how to use arrays for more info http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

If something changes and you don't know how many cards you're going to have, use an ArrayList instead
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: When I try to print these out it gives me : "[LCard;@75b84c92
[LCard;@75b84c92
[LCard;@75b84c92
[LCard;@75b84c92
[LCard;@75b84c92
[LCard;@75b84c92
[LCard;@75b84c92
[LCard;@75b84c92
[LCard;@75b84c92
[LCard;@75b84c92
[LCard;@75b84c92
[LCard;@75b84c92
[LCard;@75b84c92
[LCard;@75b84c92" I checked and my toString is fine. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Ah. I think there's a problem with your loop. If you could update your post to include all the code (particularly the closing braces '}') then that'd help. I'll update my answer with that I think is the problem

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out. Thanks so much for your help!